# Google Maps API v3 stop info box from panning map

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am creating a Google Map with a Fusion Layer so a site's visitors can get information about technicians in various states. Here is the site for reference: http://horizonwebtest.zxq.net/techmap.html The map needs to be locked to the continental United States, so I've disabled the default UI, draggable, double click zoom, keyboard shortcuts, scrollwheel and auto pan. The problem is that when the info window pops up, it still forces the map to pan. Does anyone know a way to work around this? Here is the JavaScript:

```
// JavaScript Document
  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.816223025492505, -94.15954943749999),
      zoom: 4,
      disableDefaultUI: true,
      draggable: false, 
      disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
      keyboardShortcuts: false,
      scrollwheel: false,
      disableAutoPan: true,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var horizonStyles = [
     {
        featureType: "water", 
            stylers: [ 
                { hue: "#0077ff" }, 
                { saturation: 20 }, 
                { lightness: -50 }, 
            ]
     },{
         featureType: "administrative.locality", 
            stylers: [ 
                { visibility: "off" } 
            ]
     },{
         featureType: "administrative.province",
         elementType: "labels.text.fill",
            stylers: [
                { lightness: -80 }
            ]
     }
    ];
    var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        query: {
            select: 'geometry',
            from: '18KqZR_1Nd39CyWN1kKt8Pufd6wlLS2oQArpCugw'
        },
    });
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        mapOptions);
    map.setOptions({styles: horizonStyles});
    layer.setMap(map);
}
```

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of searching and trial and error, it seems that the fusion layer does not contain editable elements. To edit the infobox, you need to set suppressInfoWindows: true and then create your info window. Here is the finished code for reference:

```
// JavaScript Document
  function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(38.816223025492505, -94.15954943749999); 
    var infoposition = new google.maps.LatLng(40, -81);
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      disableAutoPan: true,
      position: infoposition,
    });
    var infoWindowContent = '';
    var mapOptions = {
      center: latlng,
      zoom: 4,
      disableDefaultUI: true,
      draggable: false, 
      disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
      keyboardShortcuts: false,
      scrollwheel: false,
      disableAutoPan: true,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var horizonStyles = [
     {
        featureType: "water", 
            stylers: [ 
                { hue: "#0077ff" }, 
                { saturation: 20 }, 
                { lightness: -50 }, 
            ]
     },{
         featureType: "administrative.locality", 
            stylers: [ 
                { visibility: "off" } 
            ]
     },{
         featureType: "administrative.province",
         elementType: "labels.text.fill",
            stylers: [
                { lightness: -80 }
            ]
     }
    ];
    var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        query: {
            select: 'geometry',
            from: '18KqZR_1Nd39CyWN1kKt8Pufd6wlLS2oQArpCugw',
        },
        suppressInfoWindows: true,
    });
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        mapOptions);
    map.setOptions({styles: horizonStyles});
    layer.setMap(map);

//click listener on layer
google.maps.event.addListener(layer, 'click', function(e) {
if(infowindow) infowindow.close();
else infowindow;

//create info window layer
infoWindowContent = infowindow.setContent(
    '<p class="info_window" style="font-weight: bold">' + e.row['State'].value + '</p>' +
    '<p class="info_window">' + e.row['Number of Technicians'].value + ' technicians available<br>' +
    '<a href="http://horizonwebtest.zxq.net/contact/">Click here to schedule a service call or installation<br>' +
    'or <style="font-weight:bold">CALL 727-845-4444 NOW</style> for a live help desk<br>' +
    'person to assist you over the phone or to dispatch<br>' +
    'a technician to your site.</a></p>'
    );

map.setCenter(latlng);
infowindow.open(map);        
});
}
```

I hope that helps someone else...